# id getting inserted without selecting in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select project_name, ID from tb_project", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(DR);
        combo_status.DataSource = table;
        combo_status.DisplayMember = "project_name";
        combo_status.ValueMember = "ID";
        combo_status.Text = "Select Project Name";
    }

private void btnSave_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert Into tb1(name) Values (@name)", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", combo_status.SelectedValue);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");

    }
```

In the first class i have a combobox and i am fetching its value from database and i have shown "Select Project Name" on page load in combobox.I want to insert its value only when user selects option from dropdown and insert nothing if user did not choose any option.

Now the problem is that the first name in the dropdown gets inserted on button click.without choosing any option.I want that if user did not choose any name value from dropdown nothing should get inserted.

can anyone help me..?

Comment: Because your combobox selectedindex equal to 0 by default (-1 if your datasource is null), so that if you don't want to insert anything to database if user didn't select from combobox, you can add an empty row as the first item of combobox,

Comment: how to add an empty row as the first item of combobox could you please tell me??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that datatype of `ID` column is int:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select project_name, ID from tb_project", con);
    con.Open();

    OleDbDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(DR);

    //begin adding line
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["project_name"] = "Select Project Name";
    row["ID"] = 0;
    table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
    //end adding line

    combo_status.DataSource = table;
    combo_status.DisplayMember = "project_name";
    combo_status.ValueMember = "ID";
    combo_status.Text = "Select Project Name";
}

private void btnSave_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(combo_status.SelectedValue == 0)
    {
         return; //do nothing if user didn't select anything in combobox, you can change this line of code with whatever process you want
    }

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert Into tb1(name) Values (@name)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", combo_status.SelectedValue);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");

}
```

Hope this will help you